# Allocing memory to array of strings

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So, i'm tring to allocate memory to insert file names in it. I have my struct Estado defined like this:

```
typedef struct estado{

    char modo;
    char jogador;
    char matriz[8][8];
    int pretas;
    int brancas;
    char *nome[10];
    int current;

} Estado;
```

I tried doing this:

```
Estado insereFicheiro(Estado estado , char* nome){

    estado.nome[estado.current] = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    estado.nome[estado.current++] = nome;

    return estado;
}
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to specify how long will be the string and change to `estado.nome[estado.current] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char)` for example. And for assignment use `strcpy`.

Comment: @aragon, `sizeof(char) is by definition always 1 in C.

Answer (score 2):

There's two problems with the code you show:

1. With

   ```
   estado.nome[estado.current] = malloc(sizeof(char*));
   ```

   you allocate only space for a *pointer*, not the whole string. This is like you creating an array of one pointer. You need to allocate space for the string itself, whose length you get from `strlen`, and also for the null-terminator at the end:

   ```
   estado.nome[estado.current] = malloc(strlen(nome) + 1);  // +1 for null-terminator
   ```
2. With

   ```
   estado.nome[estado.current++] = nome;
   ```

   you *overwrite* the pointer you created above. This is equivalent to e.g. `int a; a = 5; a = 10;` and then be surprised that `a` is no longer equal to `5`. You need to copy the string, not the pointer:

   ```
   strcpy(estado.nome[estado.current++], nome);
   ```

Of course, you need to `free` the memory you allocate later in your code, once you're finished with it.

And of course you should have some bound-checking to make sure you don't go out of bounds of the `estado.nome` array (i.e. a check for `estado.current < 10`).

Comment: I would also suggest moving the increment out of the indexing operator, it doesn't have much advantages compared to putting it after the copy.